# Can you show me a DiffEq that uses imaginary numbers to solve?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Does anyone have a reference handy that would provide an example of the equation format below?  I would like to try solving it with my Calculus I/II skills.

https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/answers/relevance.html

In engineering and other applications, one very often has to solve an equation of the form $ay$" + $by$'+$cy$ = $0$  for the unknown function $y$. It turns out that there's a way to get the solutions provided one can solve the quadratic equation $a$r$^2$+ $br$ + $c$ = $0$ for the variable $r$. In the real numbers, there may not be any solutions. However, in the complex numbers there are, so one can find all complex-valued solutions to the equation, and then finally restrict oneself to those that are purely real-valued.

Comment: The prototypical and most important example of the phenomenon the text refers to is the harmonic oscillator: 
$$
\ddot x + \omega^2 x =  0.$$

Comment: If a homogeneous linear ODE $Ly=0$ has constant **real** coefficients then the operator $L$ does not mix up the real and imaginary parts of possible solution functions $y$. It follows that for any complex-valued solution  $y$ of $Ly=0$ both ${\rm Re}(y)$ and ${\rm Im}(y)$ are real-valued solutions of $Ly=0$.

Comment: Is your last paragraph part of your question? Or are you saying you already know how the answer goes in that situation and you are looking for another such situation where complex numbers help you solve a DE?